# I keep getting unreachable code for the return qtyValue. This is my first time using java

Tags: java

```
public static String getQtyInput(String prompt) throws Exception
{
    String qtyValue;
    int counter = 0;

    do
    {       
        qtyValue = getStringInput(prompt);
        counter = counter +1;
        qtyValue = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "Enter amount of support hours (1-99)");
    } while (counter < 3);

    if (Integer.parseInt(qtyValue) > 1 || Integer.parseInt(qtyValue) < 99); 
    {
        throw new Exception("Invalid input! \n Must enter 1-99");
    }

    return qtyValue;
}
```

Comment: remove the `;` after the if statement

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your if(..) statement has a semi-colon at the end, that shouldn't be there.

Comment: Thank you for your answer it really helped. One more question, when I enter a correct value I still get the exception, is like is in a loop that only ends after 3 tries. Any ideas?

Comment: That would have to be an issue with the getStringInput(..) method. On the 3rd iteration of the loop, when you step out of the do..while.. block, qtyValue is set to whatever is returned by that function. If that value happens to not be in the set [1, 99], you get that exception.
I think you have made a mistake in the if condition since you need to be checking if the value is < 1 or > 99 instead of what you have done.

Comment: Please mark the answer as correct since it solved the question that you posed.